# What is the marked thing called ? (android swipe disabled effect)

Tags: android, animation, effect, curve

I'm trying to find something about it and the API level of it.
It's only visible when the user reaches the end of a tabbed, swiped activity

[image]

Comment: This is visible with all scrollable views if you reach the beginning/end of it. I don't know the name of it but it's an indicator to the user, that one cannot scroll any further here. In some way or other it was there from the beginning - the way it looks in your screenshot I think was introduced with material design, so from Android 5 on up. With Holo-Design I think it was more blueish and blurred.

Comment: fading edge effect

Comment: AFAIK, it's still called overscroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/EdgeEffectCompat.html, it's used in ViewPager internally.

Answer (score 1):

It's an android attribute called `fadingEdge`. Many of the android widgets like listview, viewpager, scrollview etc use it by default. You can place it in your widgets too using `android:fadingEdge` attribute. 
Regarding the api level, it's deprecated since API 14 but you can still use it by requesting it using `android:requiresFadingEdge` attribute.

Refer to the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge) for details.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found in the Android documentation:

> You can use scrollers (Scroller or OverScroller) to collect the data
>   you need to produce a scrolling animation in response to a touch
>   event. They are similar, but OverScroller includes methods for
>   indicating to users that they've reached the content edges after a pan
>   or fling gesture. The InteractiveChart sample uses the EdgeEffect
>   class (actually the EdgeEffectCompat class) to display a "glow" effect
>   when users reach the content edges.

Link: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html